# PHP preg_split to nice array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-split

I need some help with preg_split and my code.

**I have output:**

> FGT-603906536077 # == [ Test ] name: Test == [ Test2 ] name: Test2 ==
>   [ Test.adada ] name: Test.adada == [ test_Test ] name: test_Test == [
>   test test ] name: test test == [ test-test ] name: test-test

And i need array like:

```
Array {
 [0] => Test 
 [1] => Test2 
 [2] => Test.adada
 [3] => test_Test
 [4] => test test
 [5] => test-test
}
```

I dont know how make array like i am write with my output..

Thanks!

Comment: What is your input and your current pattern ?

Comment: This is output from SSH, i need explode or split only filed inside the [ ].

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM: no you don't need to split, you need to extract.

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preg_match_all in php

```
<?php
    $your_string = "FGT-603906536077 # == [ Test ] name: Test == [ Test2 ] name: Test2 == [ Test.adada ] name: Test.adada == [ test_Test ] name: test_Test == [ test test ] name: test test == [ test-test ] name: test-test";
    preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $your_string, $out);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($out[1]);    
?>
```

output will be

```
Array {
 [0] => Test 
 [1] => Test2 
 [2] => Test.adada
 [3] => test_Test
 [4] => test test
 [5] => test-test
}
```

Comment: It's a php question.